# Datatable changing data source header of last retrieve kept

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

Good day guys, if you compare the results of the selection of **format** they are able to change sources after retrieve. But my problem is in **summary** the header of **detailed** are still kept after changing sources. How do i resolve this?

Basically I have two .php sources and i want to change the datatable's source depending on which format I have selected. I use "ajax source" but changed it to "data" to make the code snippet sample work.

And please if you see something that I have coded wrong please inform me because I am not that familiar with javascript and datatables thank you :)

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  fnRetReport();
});


function fnRetReport() {
  switch ($("#select-list").val()) {
    case 'detailed':
      //source = "seinq.php";
      source = [{
        "SE": "NICOLAS JENNIFER DIANE",
        "n": 2,
        "g": 0,
        "v": 0,
        "l": 0,
        "y": 1,
        "x": 0,
        "o": 0,
        "0": 3
      }, {
        "SE": "KING MA. KATHERINE",
        "n": 1,
        "g": 1,
        "v": 0,
        "l": 0,
        "y": 6,
        "x": 0,
        "o": 1,
        "0": 9
      }, {
        "SE": "FERRER MICHAEL JAY",
        "n": 0,
        "g": 0,
        "v": 0,
        "l": 0,
        "y": 1,
        "x": 0,
        "o": 0,
        "0": 1
      }, {
        "SE": "CASTRO ROWENA ",
        "n": 1,
        "g": 2,
        "v": 0,
        "l": 0,
        "y": 1,
        "x": 0,
        "o": 0,
        "0": 4
      }, {
        "SE": "GONZALES MARY ANN",
        "n": 11,
        "g": 1,
        "v": 0,
        "l": 0,
        "y": 2,
        "x": 0,
        "o": 8,
        "0": 22
      }, {
        "SE": "VILORIA SHERYLL",
        "n": 0,
        "g": 0,
        "v": 0,
        "l": 0,
        "y": 1,
        "x": 0,
        "o": 0,
        "0": 1
      }, {
        "SE": "DELA CRUZ JETRHO PRINCE",
        "n": 4,
        "g": 0,
        "v": 0,
        "l": 0,
        "y": 4,
        "x": 0,
        "o": 0,
        "0": 8
      }, {
        "SE": "BUGAYONG RANDY",
        "n": 3,
        "g": 4,
        "v": 0,
        "l": 0,
        "y": 2,
        "x": 0,
        "o": 12,
        "0": 21
      }, {
        "SE": "MACARAEG DIVINA",
        "n": 8,
        "g": 25,
        "v": 0,
        "l": 0,
        "y": 1,
        "x": 0,
        "o": 5,
        "0": 39
      }, {
        "SE": "ABANCE ISRAEL",
        "n": 0,
        "g": 0,
        "v": 0,
        "l": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "x": 0,
        "o": 11,
        "0": 11
      }, {
        "SE": "RAMIREZ LENAR",
        "n": 3,
        "g": 0,
        "v": 0,
        "l": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "x": 0,
        "o": 0,
        "0": 3
      }];
      seColumns = [{
        data: 'SE',
        title: 'Sales Executive'
      }, {
        data: 'n',
        title: 'For Follow Up'
      }, {
        data: 'g',
        title: 'On Going'
      }, {
        data: 'v',
        title: 'With VSP'
      }, {
        data: 'l',
        title: 'Lost Sale'
      }, {
        data: 'y',
        title: 'Sold'
      }, {
        data: 'x',
        title: 'Taken Over'
      }, {
        data: 'o',
        title: 'Open'
      }, {
        data: '0',
        title: "Grand Total"
      }];
      break;
    default:
      //source = "seinq2.php";
      source = [{
        "SE": "NICOLAS JENNIFER DIANE",
        "n": 2,
        "g": 0,
        "v": 0,
        "y": 1,
        "0": 3
      }, {
        "SE": "KING MA. KATHERINE",
        "n": 1,
        "g": 1,
        "v": 0,
        "o": 1,
        "y": 6,
        "0": 9
      }, {
        "SE": "FERRER MICHAEL JAY",
        "n": 0,
        "g": 0,
        "v": 0,
        "y": 1,
        "0": 1
      }, {
        "SE": "CASTRO ROWENA ",
        "n": 1,
        "g": 2,
        "v": 0,
        "y": 1,
        "0": 4
      }, {
        "SE": "GONZALES MARY ANN",
        "n": 11,
        "g": 1,
        "v": 0,
        "o": 8,
        "y": 2,
        "0": 22
      }, {
        "SE": "VILORIA SHERYLL",
        "n": 0,
        "g": 0,
        "v": 0,
        "y": 1,
        "0": 1
      }, {
        "SE": "DELA CRUZ JETRHO PRINCE",
        "n": 4,
        "g": 0,
        "v": 0,
        "y": 4,
        "0": 8
      }, {
        "SE": "BUGAYONG RANDY",
        "n": 3,
        "g": 4,
        "v": 0,
        "o": 12,
        "y": 2,
        "0": 21
      }, {
        "SE": "MACARAEG DIVINA",
        "n": 8,
        "g": 25,
        "v": 0,
        "o": 5,
        "y": 1,
        "0": 39
      }, {
        "SE": "ABANCE ISRAEL",
        "n": 0,
        "g": 0,
        "v": 0,
        "o": 11,
        "0": 11
      }, {
        "SE": "RAMIREZ LENAR",
        "n": 3,
        "g": 0,
        "v": 0,
        "0": 3
      }];
      seColumns = [{
        data: 'SE',
        title: 'Sales Executive'
      }, {
        data: 'n',
        title: 'For Follow Up'
      }, {
        data: 'g',
        title: 'On Going'
      }, {
        data: 'v',
        title: 'With VSP'
      }, {
        data: '0',
        title: "Grand Total"
      }];
  };

  var table = $('#seinq').empty();
  table = $('#seinq').DataTable({
    "destroy": true,
    "cache": true,
    "paging": false,
    "data": source, // + "?mret=" + mret + "&yret=" + yret,
    "columns": seColumns
  });
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <label>Format :</label>
  <select id="select-list">
    <option value="detailed">Detailed</option>
    <option value="summary">Summary</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="fnRetReport()">Retrieve</button>

  <table id='seinq' class="display">
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Images:
[Detailed Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNF8k.jpg),
[Summary Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU7Yo.jpg)

Comment: I'm sorry, your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: sorry if it confused you mike since my code is long and it includes a ready to edit snippet took my sample from my code. Aug born solved it for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$('#seinq thead tr').remove();

Add the above line before 
var table = $('#seinq').empty();

Please edit your html code. Your table should be inside body and scripts should be inside head

Comment: thank you sir you're a god send to me been figuring this out for a couple of days but you got it on the fly. I also edited the code placed them in proper head and body thank you again :)